# Search by SKU but show Grouped Products that have that SKU associated

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, e-commerce

I need my quick search to search by SKU. I know that's the way Magento works by default but unfortunately that's only for simple products (I think).

In my case, I have a store that uses simple products set to "not visible individually", and then I have grouped products that associate those simple products. Only the simple products have the SKU attribute but they're only shown when you open the grouped product.

What I need then, is to have it search inside those grouped products for the simple products with the SKU entered in the quick search field, and then display the grouped products that have a match.

Is there anything that does this? Seems to me it should be baseline in Magento.

Edit: Magento 1.4.2

Answer (score 1):

Working on this issue right now.  The solution I'm thinking of trying is suggested here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/74229/

The idea is to set the simple product visible in search instead of not individually visible.  Then in the product template check if the simple product is part of a group.  If so JavaScript redirect to the grouped product page.

Still thinking about a cleaner solution but thought this might be of some help.

Comment: Ian, just started on this again (left it in the to do list), did you ever think of anything else?

Comment: Pedro, I think I took this approach but instead of JavaScript redirects changed search result template to use parent product data as needed.

Comment: That's exactly what I did and it works wonders. I wanted to write a tutorial on how to do it as the answer for this question, but I still haven't found the time to do it. I feel this would be very useful for the community.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if people are still looking for answers to this, but i was so I'll post my resolution anyway :)

Simply add all the SKU's with a space onto the SKU of the grouped product.  Then when someone searches for one of them, it will bring up your grouped product.  Then you need to do nothing to the simple products at all, they can remain hidden.  Also works for configurable items.

Hope I help someone!

IP